# Responsive HTML Email Image Switching

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, gmail

I am trying to work out a method of replacing an image on a HTML email depending on the device it is view on (desktop or mobile).

The code below works well for devices such as iphones but as Gmail does not support media queries and neither do Yahoo as far as I am aware then maybe I should be looking for a different solution. Has anyone got any experience with a similar issue with a method that work across all devices and email clients?

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        img[class="swap"] {
        content:url("http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/17000000/Nature-s-jewerly-love-you-natures-seasons-17036569-500-500.jpg") !important;}
       } 
    </style>
</head>

 <body>
 < img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/28179582/Nature-Photography-Rain-520x520_large.jpg"     width="500" height="500" border="0" class="swap" />
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: and kind of "split the image" so desktop users see their side and mobile see theirs?

Comment: and adding JS to a HTML email is just a one way ticket to the junk box.....

Comment: You are right. Good point

Comment: Another idea, beside a div and an background-image, would be to use only one image (big enough) for both. Than add something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your header and add an inline style to your image like: `style="height: auto; max-width: 100%; width: auto;"`. Don't forget that Gmail and Yahoo have a tendency to discard non-inline CSS

Comment: yeah I know all about inlining, lets discuss this Large image method a bit more, how would we hide a portion of the image if thats what you mean?

Comment: also background-image is a bit of a no no with some email clients as well right?

Comment: Right. That's why I would rather go with the meta tag solution. Basically you use a big image and add style to it so it's always 100% by 100%. With the meta tag, you tell your page to "calculate" the width of the viewport and that tells your image to be the same width (until your image "real" width is reached).

Comment: but then both devices see the same image?

Comment: Yep. Same image for both. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/1xq6xkvf/ and play with the dividers.

Comment: Ok I think were on different paths here, what i am trying to achieve is for the mobile and desktop users to see "different" images...

For instance, desktop users see "£50 off", mobile users see "£100 off"